# Getting type mismatch error when having property as generic in base class and trying to override in derive class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class like below  which calculate some statistics for 2 different Types :

```
public abstract class BaseStatsCalculator<T>
    {
        public abstract T First { get; }
        public abstract T Second { get; }
        public abstract T ValueDiff { get; protected set; }
        public abstract T MatchingPercentage { get;}
    }
```

Now I have **2 Types** which will manipulate value of above properties in their own way.

For **Type1** I know below properties will always work with `int datatype` :

```
public abstract T First { get; }
public abstract T Second { get; }
public abstract T ValueDiff { get; protected set; }
```

I am facing problem with calculating MatchingPercentage properties because it will be calculated based on formula and also rounding will be based on **USER SELECTED CONFIGURATION FOR DECIMAL PLACES.**

```
public class Type1 : BaseStatsCalculator<int>
    {
        public override double MatchingPercentage
        {
            get {
                double a = (Second - ValueDiff) * 100;
                double b = Second;
                double matchingPercentage = 00.00;
                if (b > 0)
                    matchingPercentage = Math.Round(((double)a / b), this._decimalPlaces);
            }
        }
   }
```

Type 2 have below formula to calculate MatchingPercentage :

```
public class Type1 : BaseStatsCalculator<Decimal>
    {
       public override decimal MatchingPercentage
        {
            get {
                decimal matchPer = 0;
                if (Second > 0 || First > 0)
                matchPer = ((Math.Min(Second,First) / Math.Max(Second,First)) * 100);
                return (TruncateDecimal(matchPer, this.decimalPlaces))
            }
        }

        public decimal TruncateDecimal(decimal value, int precision)
        {
            decimal step = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
            decimal tmp = Math.Truncate(step * value);
            return tmp / step;
        }
}
```

So for type 2,I think i will have no problem but for Type1 i am facing issue here :

public override double MatchingPercentage 
    {
    }

**Error :** `It should work with int`

Can anybody please guide me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can't change a member's type when you override it. The property `MatchingPercentage` should be the same as the type specified in `BaseStatsCalculator<T>` (i.e. `int`).

Comment: well, if your generic argument is `int`, your method `MatchingPercentage` should surely return an `int`, not a `double`, shouldn´t it?

Comment: If always your MatchingPercentage is decimal, then it will be decimal in your abstract class

Comment: Seems like your `MatchingPercentage` shouldn´t be generic at all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah i agree but as you can see it is calculating based on formula so if i will take int then what about rounding and decimal places?

Comment: Your design relies on the assumption that diffs and percentages are of the same type as the values which is not always the case (if `T` is `uint`, diff may be wrong too). You can either add an extra type parameter for those or consider they'll always be of a given type.

Comment: @vc74 but taking MatchingPercentage  will remove my decimal places.Is this design not proper?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, `MatchingPercentage` and `ValueDiff` cannot be `T` instances

Comment: The question remains: why is `MatchingPercentage` generic, if you allways expect it to return decimals?

Comment: @MrBean Your definition of `MatchingPercentage` in your base class means that it will always be `T` no matter what `T` is, even if it's `string`. If `T` is `int`, `MatchingPercentage` is `int`. As you're no doubt aware, `int` can only hold _whole_ numbers.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want to reuse some common properties for both the types(Type1 and Type2).Now First,Second and ValueDiff will always be int for Type1 and Decimal for Type2 so for type 2 there wont be an y problem.Now only problem is with Type1 for MatchingPercentage.Ok i think i got your point that it should be decimal always

Comment: @vc74 Thanks for the suggestion.Do you think making MatchingPercentage  as decimal will make sense as for Type 2 is also working with decimal??

Comment: @John Yes right so now in order for MatchingPercentage to return correct result with decimal points what do you suggest?

Comment: Don´t mix **data** with **representation**. A decimal-point is something you want to show in your GUI (the represenation). However this point does not exist on a number (which is the data). So your method shouldn´t care for decimal-points at all. your GUI however should.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Actually I am having this is as a class library which is performing some operation and then based on that calculating statistics and store it in database.